# Leaflet will not display my marker, "TypeError: t is null"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, leaflet, coordinates

I am trying to display a marker on my Leaflet map. This gives me the following error: TypeError: t is null

PHP code which uses Google Maps API to fetch co-ordinates:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["checkAddress"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $checkAddress = $_POST["checkAddress"];
    $plus = str_replace(" ", "+", $checkAddress);
    $json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $plus . '&key=KEY');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $mapLat = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $mapLng = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    $coords = ('' . $mapLat . ', ' . $mapLng . '');
    echo $coords;
}
?>
```

jQuery which runs the PHP script and should display the co-ordinates on the Leaflet map:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "geo.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
         checkAddress: $("#largetxt").val()
        },
        success: function(response){
         console.log(response);
         var marker = L.marker([response]).addTo(map);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh, it's you again.

You are receiving a string as a response.

L.marker expects `[lat, lng]` but you are giving it `["lat, lng"]` A string instead of two floats.

To fix this in JavaScript:

```
success: function(response){
    var coordinates = response.split(", "); //create an array containing lat and lng as strings
    coordinates[0] = parseFloat(coordinates[0]); //convert lat string to number
    coordinates[1] = parseFloat(coordinates[1]); //convert lng string to number
    var marker = L.marker(coordinates).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: Genius! I learned something new today with your split array. Thank you sincerely for helping me.

Comment: I recommend you create an array in PHP and `json_encode` it instead. Then, `JSON.parse` it in JavaScript. @TJW